MarketingCloudSDK | In App Messaging | Button URLs not handled
I'm using MarketingCloudSDK iOS 8.1.2 version.
I'm not able to handle the action from the app in message.
this is my code :
In appdelagte configure I set:
SFMCSdk.requestPushSdk { mp in
            mp.setURLHandlingDelegate(URLHandler())
        }




@objc class URLHandler: NSObject, URLHandlingDelegate {
        func sfmc_handleURL(_ url: URL, type: String) {
            // Very simply, send the URL returned from the MobilePush SDK to UIApplication to handle correctly.
            UIApplication.shared.open(url,
                                      options: [:],
                                      completionHandler: {
                (success) in
                debugPrint("Open \(url): \(success)")
            })
        }
    }

How can I fix this issue?
